# Unificar información de un objeto con Ramda

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Requiero de su apoyo para generar el siguiente resultado en ramda.

He realizado algunas formas y he llegado a estos resultados pero ahora lo que necesito es que se haga como un merge por el 'productCode' generando el siguiente resultado, donde va a ser 'serviceType' un array que está ordenado y relacionado por 'duration':

> Data:

```
data = [{
    id: 'ck5ii4yr704vc0744sjw3tljd',
    pdvIntegrationStatus: 'WAITING',
    sapIntegrationStatus: 'INTEGRATED',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-17T18:34:13.075Z',
    category: { description: 'Celular e Smartphones' },
    serviceType: { description: 'descrição da garantia estendida' },
    productCode: '4004593',
    duration: [ 12 ]
  },
  {
    id: 'ck5ii4ysl04vn0744z7liu0f3',
    pdvIntegrationStatus: 'WAITING',
    sapIntegrationStatus: 'WAITING',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-17T18:34:13.075Z',
    category: { description: 'Celular e Smartphones' },
    serviceType: { description: 'descrição SEGURO ROUBO OU FURTO' },
    productCode: '4004593',
    duration: [ 24 ]
  }]
```

> Resultado:

```
result = {
    id: 'ck5ii4ysl04vn0744z7liu0f3',
    pdvIntegrationStatus: 'WAITING',
    sapIntegrationStatus: 'WAITING',
    updatedAt: '2020-01-17T18:34:13.075Z',
    category: { description: 'Celular e Smartphones' },
    serviceType: [{ description: 'descrição da garantia estendida' }, { description: 'descrição SEGURO ROUBO OU FURTO' }],
    productCode: '4004593',
    duration: [ 12, 24 ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

he realizado pruebas y he conseguido este resultado, aunque creo que habra una manera mejor de hacerlo para a futuro poder darle un mejor mantenimiento al codigo:

```
const groupByTransaction = R.groupBy(R.prop('productCode'));

const durationMerge = (data) => Object.values(data).map( item => (   {
    ...pickAll(['productCode'], item[0]),
    ...pickAll(['category'], item[0]),
    id: R.pluck('id', item),
    pdvIntegrationStatus: R.pluck('pdvIntegrationStatus', item),
    sapIntegrationStatus: R.pluck('sapIntegrationStatus', item),
    updatedAt: R.pluck('updatedAt', item),
    serviceType: R.pluck('serviceType', item),
    duration: R.pluck('duration', item)   } ));

const hasDuplicates = R.pipe(   groupByTransaction,   map(uniq),   durationMerge );

hasDuplicates(data);
```

Comment: He realizado la prueba en el siguiente link [https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1]

Comment: A la final cambie el tipo de consulta de GRAPHQL hacia un query disrecto en la base de datos SQL Server.